# Separate numbers retrieved from one database field

Tags: mysql, asp-classic

Not sure if this possible:

I have a checkbox list as follows:

```
<input type='checkbox' name="item" value="<%=rs("ID")%>" /> <%= rs("Item Name") %>
```

I'm then taking the values selected:

```
item_id = request.form("item")
```

which writes to a database field called to item_selected which is varchar(50) and is recorded like this in the database:

31, 32, 45

also not sure how that has worked, as it is not an array (to my knowledge) and I didn't explicitly comma separate the values.

But what I would like to do is retrieve the values and loop through each ID and make that option 'checked' (only check the items they selected), this is for an update order page.

I've tried to do this by getting all item id's and trying to compare to ID's they have selected and using 'checked' to check that option

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You only show one checkbox, but I suspect that they all have the same name. That's how they end up as an array.

Comment: Yeah thought so, that was my first inclination but wasn't sure. It loops through all the ID's for which the user can select which items they want. All with this 'name = "item"'

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to know how to mark the checkboxes as checked based on what's in the field. You could convert the field value to an array, and as you create each checkbox, search the array for the value of the particular checkbox. If found, add the checked='checked' to the tag.

Comment: Correct: but not sure how to do it, I've tried converting the retrieved value for e.g. 31, 32, 45 into an array and then looping each ID as you say, just not sure what the code would look like or some idea of how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you would need to get the field value with the selected items (your comma separated id string). Something like this:

```
Set rs = conn.execute("SELECT item_selected FROM tblTable WHERE iID = intSomeID") 'remember to handle SQL Injection
If Not rs.EOF Then
    strItemSelected = rs("item_selected") & ","
End If
rs.Close() : Set rs = Nothing
```

I don't know where your checkboxes is coming from. But suppose they are coming from the database. Then it would look something like this:

```
Set rs = conn.execute("SELECT ID, ItemName FROM tblCheckboxes")
If Not rs.EOF Then
    While Not rs.EOF
        strChecked = ""
        If InStr(strItemSelected, CStr(rs("ID")) & ",") > 0 Then
            strChecked = " checked=""checked"""
        End If
        Response.Write("<input type=""checkbox"" name=""item"" value=""" & rs("ID") & """" & strChecked & " /> " & rs("ItemName") & "<br/>")
        rs.Movenext
    Wend
End If
rs.Close() : Set rs = Nothing
```

I have not tested this code but should work but you probably need to adjust it a little to fit your scenario.

You could also split the selected items on comma like this:

```
arrItemSelected = Split(rs("item_selected"),",")
```

And then in the code that loops and writes out the checkboxes you could check if the value is in the array instead of doing the InStr(). But you would need to write a function for that or grab some function from the Internet that does this because VBScript has no built-in function that does this as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Initially when the user has selected items, it is saved to the database like this (in a varchar(50)): 31, 22, 33. What I would need to is when I retrieve this field again is to compare each ID with Item ID's and check all the ones the user selected

Comment: I have some sort of idea (may be wrong) which is to get the field, strip all the commas and spaces so you'd get 313233 then in a while loop until the variable is empty is to take the first 2 chars/numbers which would be 31 then compare this to each item and when matched make that checkbox checked BUT only problem is the ID field is auto increment and obviously it starts from 1 which is one char/number. Not sure how your solution would work, I am new to this programming language so it might just be my lack of knowledge.

Comment: could change this field in the database to save as ''01, 02, 03' etc

Comment: UPDATE: you solution worked perfectly - just had to understand what it did first :D

Comment: one more question, with this solution, if i have an ID: 21 and an ItemID 1 and 21, it selects 21 but also selects 1, I'm sure it something with the InStr, been trying to fix it but getting no where, would you know how to fix it?

Comment: If you change the instr to: InStr(strItemSelected, CStr("," & rs("ID")) & ",") it would probably work but then you would need to add a comma in the beginning of the strItemSelected string (strItemSelected=","&strItemSelected) or the first one would not match. There is probably a bettery way but nothing I can think of at the moment.